# Excel PowerQuery - Best way to import SQL Server Logs with correct DateTime conversion?

Tags: excel, datetime, powerquery

In SQL Server I often check error logs directly in SSMS, but when I export them as CSV files, the DateTime component is converted from Australian to US format.

This is what it shows - in AUS format:

[image]

But this is how it's imported into Excel - US format:

[image]

I've tried to import the LOG file using *PowerQuery*, but it doesn't detect the column is a *DateTime* column, and when I try and convert it, I get Error.

[image]

[image]

I thought PowerQuery was "smart" to know the data types of columns. If I have to Add Columns by stripping the text into its date components, I might as well have just done it in the vanilla File Open CSV wizard.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Power query, right click on the column and select

- Change Type
- Using Locale

[image]

- Pick Date/Time and English(Australia)

[image]

It will then be converted into a "real" date/time.
Of course, it will be displayed in PQ in accordance with your Windows Regional Settings short-date format.

Once you load it into Excel, you can change the cell `numberformat` to display it in the date/time format of your choice.